# NoClassDefFoundError for aws lambda function in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

I have a java lambda function to invoke another lambda function. The code is as below,

```
 package com.example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambda;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeResult;

public class InvokeLambda {
    public String myHandler(String input){
        AWSLambda lambdaClient = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        InvokeRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest()
                .withFunctionName("testLambdaFunction")
                .withPayload("{ \"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\" }");

        InvokeResult invokeResult = lambdaClient.invoke(invokeRequest);

        String functionOutput = new String(invokeResult.getPayload().array());
        System.out.println(functionOutput);
        return input;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml code is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>invokelambda</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>invokelambda</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.66</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.76</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I'm locally building the jar file using `mvn package` command and create the jar file and upload it to the lambda function in aws. I am getting the below error,

```
"errorMessage": "com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClientBuilder",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.example.InvokeLambda.myHandler(InvokeLambda.java:10)",
    "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
    "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
    "java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"
  ],
```

I have tried removing and reinstalling the packages and yet this is giving the same error without a change. How can I resole this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this. In your POM file, you are referencing the AWS SDK for Java V2., See:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.66</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

And other places in your POM - you use V1 dependencies. You are mixing V1 and V2 - which is bad practice and leads to errors you are seeing.

In your code, you are attemping to use AWS SDK for Java V1. This is a V1 Java class:

```
com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambda
```

V2 is

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaClient
```

To invoke a Lambda function using the V2 Client, you would use this Java code.

```
// snippet-start:[lambda.java2.LambdaInvoke.complete]
package com.example.lambda;

// snippet-start:[lambda.java2.invoke.import]
import org.json.JSONObject;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvokeResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.LambdaException;
// snippet-end:[lambda.java2.invoke.import]

public class LambdaInvoke {

   /*
   *  Function names appear as arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:335556666777:function:HelloFunction
   *  you can retrieve the value by looking at the function in the AWS Console
   *
   * Also, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
   *
   * For information, see this documentation topic:
   *
   * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
   */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <functionName> \n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    functionName - The name of the Lambda function \n";

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String functionName = args[0];
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        LambdaClient awsLambda = LambdaClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();

        invokeFunction(awsLambda, functionName);
        awsLambda.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[lambda.java2.invoke.main]
    public static void invokeFunction(LambdaClient awsLambda, String functionName) {

        InvokeResponse res = null ;
        try {
            // Need a SdkBytes instance for the payload.
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            jsonObj.put("inputValue", "2000");
            String json = jsonObj.toString();
            SdkBytes payload = SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(json) ;

            // Setup an InvokeRequest.
            InvokeRequest request = InvokeRequest.builder()
                .functionName(functionName)
                .payload(payload)
                .build();

            res = awsLambda.invoke(request);
            String value = res.payload().asUtf8String() ;
            System.out.println(value);

        } catch(LambdaException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[lambda.java2.invoke.main]
}
// snippet-end:[lambda.java2.LambdaInvoke.complete]
```

You can find this example and other Lambda V2 code examples in the AWS Example Github here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/lambda

You can also look at the POM file used for V2.

To fix your issue, replace the V1 code in your Lambda handler with the V2 code. Make sure your POM file has only V2 depedencies and not a mix of V1 and V2.

Also - you should upgrade to Java 1.8 from 1.7 that you have in your POM.